# How to override JavaScript files in child theme?

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I'm loading some JavaScript files in the parent theme. The path in the parent theme is:

```
scripts > custom.js
```

In the child theme, I'm creating the same path (`scripts > custom.js`) and changing some of the jQuery inside the `custom.js` file.

The problem is that the changes are not being applied. Is this the wrong way to make changes to these files in the child theme?

Comment: What is the parent Theme? How are the scripts being *called* by the parent Theme?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Child themes only override php files (like header.php) that are included with functions like get_template_part or get_header, etc.

The correct way to add scripts to WordPress is with [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).  If your parent theme uses this, you can override the JS files by using [wp_dequeue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) and enqueuing your own.

Like so...

```
<?php
// hook in late to make sure the parent theme's registration 
// has fired so you can undo it. Otherwise the parent will simply
// enqueue its script anyway.
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse26822_script_fix', 100);
function wpse26822_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('parent_theme_script_handle');
    wp_enqueue_script('child_theme_script_handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/scripts/yourjs.js', array('jquery'));
}
```

If the parent theme isn't using wp_enqueue_script, it's probably hooking into wp_head (or wp_footer) to echo out the scripts there.  So you'd use [remove_action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action) to get rid of those functions echoing the scripts out, and then enqueue your own script.

If the script is hard coded into the template file, you'll just need to replace that template file in your child theme without the script tag.

If they used wp_enqueue_script calls that utilize [get_stylesheet_directory_uri](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri), then you shouldn't have to do anything.  Since this isn't happening, you'll just have to poke around and see what the theme author did.

Comment: if the parent theme uses get_stylesheet_directory_uri to enqueue scripts, then the child theme will **have** to duplicate all scripts thus enqueued, because otherwise they woun't be found. There is no fallback mechanism in get_stylesheet_directory_uri to check if an **individual file** exists in the child theme and fall back to the parent theme's file if necessary.

Comment: From the Codex: 
“wp_print_scripts should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the front page. Use wp_enqueue_scripts instead. ”
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_print_scripts

Comment: Keep in mind when this was written: two years ago. Before `wp_enqueue_scripts` could be used to only enqueue scripts on the front end. Updated. If you see something out of date, feel free to edit.

Comment: Sorry, no criticism implied, I did upvote your answer :)

Comment: Please note that you may have to set a late priority (for instance 100) to make sure your dequeue happens *after* the parent theme enqueue. 

`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse26822_script_fix', 100 );`

from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

Comment: Update for 2016: according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507179/wp-dequeue-script-for-child-theme-to-replace-script we also have to use `wp_deregister_script('parent-script-handle');` to completely remove the parent script. Indeed, it didn't work for me without it. WP 4.6.1

Comment: can you answer my question here please? This answer is a bit confusing:https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286957/modifying-js-files-in-child-theme

Comment: @PhiLho, I'm using 5.4, and `wp_dequeue_script()` *did* work for me by itself. The parent theme had `wp_enqueue_script( 'fitvids', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/fitvids.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );` -- maybe it has to do with the way the script was loaded by the parent theme?

Comment: @PhiLho, I also added `wp_deregister_script`, this changed nothing, but maybe released some memory uselessly held by the script registration. I also had to add two actions for 'wp_enqueue_scripts', the default-priority to load my css override sheet, but to get rid of the script I added another, with the priority 100, as the answer suggested. But the fact it did not work cannot be explained by the load order fiasco, because in my case, unloading or deregistering in the normal-priotiry hook only logged errors. Strange, in any case.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it is important to prioritize both the add_action and the wp_enqueue_script function calls like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse26822_script_fix', 20120207);
function wpse26822_script_fix()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('storefront-navigation');
    wp_enqueue_script('my_storefront-navigation', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/navigation.min.js', array('jquery'),20151110,true);
}
```

In this case, wp_enqueue_scripts was called by the parent with a priority of 20120206 (the date) and so this action is added with a priority just barely greater so that it will immediately be dequeued. Then, the enqueue statement that follows that follows is actually prioritized after that to ensure that it loads after the old one was dequeued. The true, in this case is also important because that specifies that it is to be enqueued in the footer, which is where the parent script was first enqueued.

Also, I can't quite explain it entirely, but I notice that if you are careful with dequeuing the initial script immediately after it being enqueued, it seems you can effectively prevent it from loading in the first place.

Comment: The function `wp_enqueue_script` doesn't have a priority parameter, it's only a version number which is concatenated to the end of the path as a query string. _This parameter is used to ensure that the correct version is sent to the client regardless of caching [...]_

Answer (score 1):

call [wp_deregister_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/) before register your own version

Comment: Why? This is only needed when you are using the same handle – something you don't have to do. You probably even shouldn't, because it is easier to debug code whose source is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
// enqueue your required script file
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_child_theme_js_file_override');
function your_child_theme_js_file_override(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child_theme_script_handle', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/your-file.js', array('jquery' ) );
}

// dequeue your required script file
function your_child_theme_js_file_dequeue() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'parent_theme_script_handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'your_child_theme_js_file_dequeue', 100 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Since WordPress Version 4.7 you can use 'get_theme_file_uri()' which will first look in your child theme folder and afterwards in the parent theme folder. This way, the file in the child theme will be prioritized.

```
   wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_theme_file_uri() . '/scripts/custom.js');
```