# Modifying JS files in Child-theme

Tags: theme-development, javascript, child-theme

I am using tyche-child theme to modify some files.
I Am copying the file from Parent to child like:

**Parent theme**: **`wp-content/themes/tyche/assets/js/functions.js`**

**child theme**:
**`wp-content/themes/tyche-child/assets/js/functions.js`**

But nothing takes effect, only if i modify parent theme it takes effect. The full code of the file i am copying can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FLVM82A0MU79). Note that i am not using and comments in the file.

Comment: it doesn't work like you excped for JS file .. it's not like template file where you simply need to copy and modifiy, for JS/CSS files you need to be explicit and register them and maybe de-register the parent one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override JavaScript files in child theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26822/how-to-override-javascript-files-in-child-theme)

Comment: Can you answer me a solution to my answer please? Do i need to add commenting in the js file of the child theme? Also how can i add the js file inside the child theme? Just the single js file or with the folders path

Comment: no, you need to register the JS file ... adding a js into folder has no effect, your file is not considered (you can check the source code of the page)

Comment: Read the duplicate question and you will get exactly what you need with details

Comment: that answer is probably outdated since it is 5 years old and is also unclear. that guy uses php?? I want to modify js file

Comment: Yes you need to use PHP in order to register the Script .. you need to write code inside the  function.php function

Comment: before editing your JS, it need to be included in your page ... that's why you need PHP and registration

Comment: i am adding that code in the functions.php but nothing works

Comment: not the same code ... you need to read carefully the answer understand how it works, check the links, see how enqueue/dequeue works .. then you write YOUR specific code, it's not a generic code

Comment: Nvm not going to use js in the child,  at least not for now